# Symfony VichUploaderBundle: Mapping not found for field "xx"

Tags: symfony, file-upload, vichuploaderbundle

I read the VichUploaderBundle [documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), and I apply what I learn from it to my code.
But when I try to run the code I get this Exception **Mapping not found for field "logoFile"**.
Note: *I'm using Symfony 4.1, and VichUploaderBundle 1.8*
So here is my code ...

**Configuration**

```
// config/packges/vich_uploader.yaml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        company_logo:
            uri_prefix: /uploads/logos
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/logos'         
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

**Entity**:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @UniqueEntity("registrationNumber", message="This Registration Number {{ value }} is already used")
 */
class Company
{
    // ...

    /*
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="company_logo", fileNameProperty="logo")
     */
    private $logoFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $logo;

    public function getLogo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    public function setLogo(?string $logo): self
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setLogoFile(?File $image = null): self
    {
        $this->logoFile = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogoFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->logoFile;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Form**:

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
               // ...
               ->add('logoFile', VichImageType::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to clear cache?

Comment: Yes, I clear it using: bin/console cache:clear, but nothing happens !

Comment: Do you have imported @Vich annotation in your entity class?

Comment: Yes I do, its already imported !

Comment: can you please post whole entity code?

Comment: It's too long, I will try to put all related code to logo

Comment: Can you try to add `@ORM\Entity` to your class annotation? I think it might be the cause

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you write

```
/*
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="company_logo", fileNameProperty="logo")
 */
```

instead of

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="company_logo", fileNameProperty="logo")
 */
```

(check the first line ;) )

PS: If you use Easy admin, take care in your form description you need to target the "logoFile" property instead of "logo"

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is obviously with the Form, Entity is fine and according to the Vich docs (it seems). Please check the documentation on its usage with Symfony forms:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html

Comment: ... maybe, when I use FileType instead of VichImageType, the exception disappeared but the uploading process not working !